# Javascript - How to add prompt input into array and if it was canceld

Tags: javascript

I`m having some issue with Javascript. We just started to study it a couple weeks ago and I have to do a work for class:

Need to do a prompt. Until the prompt area is confirmed array + entered value through the prompt from user.If prompt was canceled then console.log(Array)
Thank you for help.

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?  What is your specific question?  You are encouraged to learn about how we can help you here: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Check the return value of [`prompt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use recursion

```js
var arr=[];
function h(){
var a=prompt('enter something');
if(a!==null)
{
arr.push(a);
h();
}
else
console.log(arr)
}
h();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The point using recursion when a `do while()` can do the job ?

Comment: If this is the answer you were looking, mark it as correct so it can help others too.